# Rewrite rules to match requests starting with and without #

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create rewrite rules to match requests that do and don't begin with a hash symbol but I can't get it to match the request that does start with a hash.  The request would look something like this:

https://blah.com/#2342353q245

Here is what I've tried:

```
RewriteRule !^/\x23(.*)$ https://example1.com [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/\x23(.*)$ https://example2.com [R=301,L,NE]
```

No matter what I always get redirected to example1.com.  I've tried swapping the rules around as well.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Anything starting with a `#` is not sent to web server. It is all handled on client side only.

Comment: @anubhava The hash can be sent to the server if it's encoded with `%23`. However, OP's example does suggest that you are correct and it's called a fragment.

Comment: The resulting URL in the browser is https://blah.com/#2342353q245, not https://blah.com/%232342353q245.  So you're saying I can't do anything with mod_rewrite in that case?

Comment: No, it should be handled in Javascript

Comment: Thanks for the help.  We've found another direction to go with this.